# PHP MySQL availability table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a doctors availability table for the week. There are 3 doctors at the surgery (Curly, Moe, Larry). All 3 doctors must be in each cell at all times, e.g cell monday - 9am-10am should firstly display the doctor which has an appointment during that time, i have this working. My problem is how do i get it to print below that doctor the remaining 2 doctors names. The reason for this is because once i have this part figured out i will need to colour code these doctors, red if booked, green if available.

PHP page:

```
<?php
$servername = "???";
$username = "???";
$password = "???";
$dbname = "???";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT doctor FROM booking WHERE datereq BETWEEN '2015-11-02 09:00:00' AND '2015-11-02 10:00:00'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "
<table width='80%' align='center' >
<div id='head_nav'>
<tr>";
echo"<th>Time</th>
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
</tr>
</div>";

echo"<tr><th>09:00 - 10:00</th><td>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br>". $row["doctor"]. "<br>";
echo "<br>". $row["doctor"]. "<br>";
echo "<br>". $row["doctor"]. "<br>";

}
} else {
echo "0 Results";
}

$sql = "SELECT doctor FROM booking WHERE datereq BETWEEN '2015-11-03 10:00:00' AND '2015-11-03 11:00:00'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo"<tr><th>10:00 - 11:00</th><td>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br>". $row["doctor"]. "<br>";
echo "<br>". $row["doctor"]. "<br>";
echo "<br>". $row["doctor"]. "<br>";

}
} else {
echo "0 Results";
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: error reporting and a try catch appear to be missing. Likely missing a `while` loop

Comment: post some sample data of the records from the table

Comment: here's a stub. Play with it a bit: http://pastie.org/10605628

Comment: the 9-10am query above is getting the information from this row in my table:
surname - Abbasi
id - 1098
amORpm - AM
datereq - 2015-11-02 09:00:00
doctor - Larry
altamORpm - N
altdate - N
altdoctor - N
date - 2015 -04-01 00:00:00
booked - Y

Comment: sorry its not letting me add any images, would be easier to show.. @arun krish

Comment: great, ill try make that work now, thanks @Drew

Comment: I tried implementing your code, i keep getting a "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement" on line 16?

I have added my code here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51747956/docstest.php  @Drew

Comment: it is because of error reporting, it is warning you it can be slow (so it is a good heads up). That would be a good column to have an index on (the date column)

Comment: try this http://pastie.org/10605672 but you need an index on that column to prevent a dreaded **table scan**. So regardless of what you have for error reporting, without an index, it does a table scan

Comment: Great ill try it out. Ill research into index and preventing a table scan as im not too familiar with it as of yet. Thanks @Drew

Comment: sure thing. Pop into http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/random-musings-drew and ask away whenever. I think one needs 20 rep to chat

Comment: Oh wicked, i will do later on today if need be. Thanks alot @Drew

Comment: @Drew thanks thats working fine now. Do you have any ideas on how i can get it to print the remaining 2 doctors names below the doctor that is pulled from the database by the query? so i need it to print larry if his got an appointment at 9am-10am on monday, the system should automatically know larry is in table so it will print curly and moe. any ideas that could help me move forward or something to look into that will be helpful for this?

Sorry cannot chat yet, need 20 reputation..

Comment: a left join perhaps. I don't know your schema, data, desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses your schema seen in comments and elsewhere. I cleaned it up a bit. And it makes your timeslots table maintenance free, as opposed to the one you had. Yours had new rows in the timeslots table. Daily. To me, it should all reside in the `booking` table.

So in the following result sets, you see that I just keep building on the prior, bringing in the information. Baby steps to put the grid together.

### Schema

```
drop table if exists doctors;
create table doctors 
(   doctorId int(4) primary key,
    doctorName varchar(20) not null -- avoid nulls when they wouldn't be anyway
);

insert into doctors (doctorId, doctorName) values 
('1234', 'Larry'),
('6568', 'Moe'),
('9012', 'Curly');

drop table if exists timeSlots;
create table timeSlots 
(   -- note the timeSlots are not iced in stone
    -- you can wedge other timeslots in the gaps (like 09:30), just order by theTime
    --
    -- so it does not matter that you get the auto incs of timeslots all sequential
    -- when you first make it (timeslot #10 can be 9:30 later if you write it right)
    --
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    theTime time not null   -- avoid mysql keywords or reserved words
    -- this digresses from your model. It is easily maintainable
    -- and does not turn timeSlots (generic) into a booking table. You already have that
    -- so in theory, this table could have as little as 10 to 35 rows max, ever
);

insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('09:00:00');    -- 1
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('10:00:00');    -- 2
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('11:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('12:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('13:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('14:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('15:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('16:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('17:00:00');    -- 9

-- select * from doctors;
-- select * from timeSlots;

drop table if exists booking;
create table booking
(   -- surname varchar(20), -- no, de-normalized
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    patientId int not null,
    -- amORpm varchar(2), no, de-normalized
    apptDate date not null, -- needs an index
    timeSlotId int not null,
    doctorId int(4),
    key(apptDate) -- new index
    -- other indexes
    -- foreign key constraints too
);

truncate table booking;
insert into booking (patientId, apptDate, timeSlotId, doctorId) values
(1738, '2015-11-30', 1, 1234),
(1991, '2015-11-30', 3, 6568),
(1098, '2015-11-30', 7, 9012),
(1934, '2015-12-02', 2, 6568),
(1432, '2015-12-02', 8, 1234);

drop table if exists updatepersonal;
create table updatepersonal (
    surname varchar(20),
    id int(4),
    forename varchar(20),
    DOB datetime,
    doctorId  int not null,
    contactno char(11),
    email varchar(40),
    address varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into updatepersonal (surname, id, forename, DOB, doctorId, contactno, email, address) values 
('Yates', 1738, 'Keith', '1964-12-02', 1234, '01610736018', 'ky@hotmail.com', '3 Abbey Road, M159GD'),
('Smith', 1032, 'Douglas', '1970-04-12', 6568, '01613470293', 'smith@hotmail.com', '34 Oxford Road, M139GD'),
('Abbasi', 1098, 'Tauqeer', '1964-12-02', 1234, '01618390932', 'abbasit@hotmail.co.uk', '63 Somerville Road, M129KD'),
('Aqeel', 1934, 'Hussain', '1970-04-12', 6568, '01618390479', 'aqeelh@hotmail.com', '100 Wilmslow Road, M167HB'),
('John', 1432, 'Michel', '1964-12-02', 1234, '01613905853', 'johnm@hotmail.com', '387 Stratford Road, M113SD');
```

The first query is to get our feet wet. Show the time slots for a given day with a cross join against all doctors. Note the `order by`.

```
select ts.id,ts.theTime,d.doctorId,d.doctorName 
from timeSlots ts 
cross join doctors d 
order by ts.theTime,d.doctorName;

+----+----------+----------+------------+
| id | theTime  | doctorId | doctorName |
+----+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | 09:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  1 | 09:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  1 | 09:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  2 | 10:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  2 | 10:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  2 | 10:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  3 | 11:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  3 | 11:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  3 | 11:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  4 | 12:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  4 | 12:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  4 | 12:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  5 | 13:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  5 | 13:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  5 | 13:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  6 | 14:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  6 | 14:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  6 | 14:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  7 | 15:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  7 | 15:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  7 | 15:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  8 | 16:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  8 | 16:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  8 | 16:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
|  9 | 17:00:00 |     9012 | Curly      |
|  9 | 17:00:00 |     1234 | Larry      |
|  9 | 17:00:00 |     6568 | Moe        |
+----+----------+----------+------------+
```

The following expands it further to show the appointments for one date.

```
select ts.id as tsId,ts.theTime,d.doctorId as docId,d.doctorName,b.id as bookingId 
from timeSlots ts 
cross join doctors d 
left join booking b 
on b.apptDate='2015-11-30' and b.timeSlotId=ts.id and b.doctorId=d.doctorId 
order by ts.theTime,d.doctorName;

+------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
| tsId | theTime  | docId | doctorName | bookingId |
+------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
|    1 | 09:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    1 | 09:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |         1 |
|    1 | 09:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    2 | 10:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    2 | 10:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    2 | 10:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    3 | 11:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    3 | 11:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    3 | 11:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |         2 |
|    4 | 12:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    4 | 12:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    4 | 12:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    5 | 13:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    5 | 13:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    5 | 13:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    6 | 14:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    6 | 14:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    6 | 14:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    7 | 15:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |         3 |
|    7 | 15:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    7 | 15:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    8 | 16:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    8 | 16:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    8 | 16:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
|    9 | 17:00:00 |  9012 | Curly      |      NULL |
|    9 | 17:00:00 |  1234 | Larry      |      NULL |
|    9 | 17:00:00 |  6568 | Moe        |      NULL |
+------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

The following expands on it, with a different column by date starting with a Monday as you wanted, if you pass in a Monday as a date. So if that is what your start Day of Week needs to be, then that is what you need to pass in.

It is accomplished by a cross join, then left joins by day. And it brings your data parameter (the date, the Monday) in via a cross join at the bottom (the Monday date) which simply becomes a `variable`, `@Monday`.

```
select ts.theTime,d.doctorName, 
bMon.id as bMon, bTue.id as bTue, bWed.id as bWed, bThu.id as bThu, bFri.id as bFri 
from timeSlots ts 
cross join doctors d 
left join booking bMon 
on bMon.apptDate=@Monday and bMon.timeSlotId=ts.id and bMon.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bTue 
on bTue.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and bTue.timeSlotId=ts.id and bTue.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bWed 
on bWed.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 2 DAY) and bWed.timeSlotId=ts.id and bWed.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bThu 
on bThu.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 3 DAY) and bThu.timeSlotId=ts.id and bThu.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bFri 
on bFri.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 4 DAY) and bFri.timeSlotId=ts.id and bFri.doctorId=d.doctorId 
cross join (select @Monday:='2015-11-30') params 
order by ts.theTime,d.doctorName;

+----------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| theTime  | doctorName | bMon | bTue | bWed | bThu | bFri |
+----------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 09:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 09:00:00 | Larry      |    1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 09:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 10:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 10:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 10:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL |    4 | NULL | NULL |
| 11:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 11:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 11:00:00 | Moe        |    2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 12:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 12:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 12:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 13:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 13:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 13:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 14:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 14:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 14:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15:00:00 | Curly      |    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 16:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 16:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL |    5 | NULL | NULL |
| 16:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 17:00:00 | Curly      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 17:00:00 | Larry      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 17:00:00 | Moe        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So the above is your grid of appointments. Keep going with this theme, joining on the patient table to display their lastname in the 5 far right columns. Or whatever. That is trivial. But this answer is getting too long to read.

If the data is not null, it has an appointment (green text as you said). If it is `NULL`, there is no appointment yet for that slot of doctor and time.

Comment: That is brilliant, that would of taken me months to do lol. thank you :),
so now i would print this query onto a table in php as i was doing before, 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br>". $row[""]. "<br>"; @Drew

Comment: sorry i'm quite new at php and mysql, i have never printed a complex query to a table before :/ @Drew

Comment: well you get in your while loop and display it after you decide if you want Last Names brought in for patients or whatever (having finalized what your final query is going to be). Do your colors as you jam it into an html table

Comment: But I would recommend some PHP and any other tutorials on your journey. If you have found this Answer helpful, please upvote. I have to head out to other questions having spent too much time here on this one. But I knew you needed the help. Gotta scoot